# Unresolved external linker error in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, unresolved-external

I am new to C++ Builder. I am translating a Delphi project into C++. I have translated some of the Delphi code into C++ and it compiles fine in C++Builder, but I get an error:

> Unresolved external ColorClasses::TColorList:: referenced from ...

when I use the `TColorList` constructor in my MainForm in this way:

```cpp
ColorClasses::TColorList *cl;

cl = new ColorClasses::TColorList();
```

The `TColorList` constructor is defined as follows in file `ColorClasses.cpp`:

```cpp
__fastcall ColorClasses::TColorList::TColorList() : TColorClass()
{
  fcolor_list = new TList();
}
```

The `TColorList` class is declared as follows in file `ColorClasses.h`:

```
class DELPHICLASS TColorList;

class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TColorList : public TColorClass
{
private:
  TList* fcolor_list;

public:
  __fastcall TColorList();
  virtual __fastcall ~TColorList();
};
```

I have searched the StackOverflow site for similar questions relevant to C++Builder, but I can't find one specific to my problem.

Comment: if you have __fastcall ColorClasses::TColorList::TColorList() constructor in your .cpp, the declaration in the .h must match this giving you the error., I could be wrong though.

Comment: I have namespace ColorClasses { ... } in ColorClasses.h so I don't need exactly the same declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to resolve itself if I remove the keywords DELPHICLASS and PASCALIMPLEMENTATION.

Comment: Yes, you need to remove those, since the `.h` file does not refer to a class that is implemented in Delphi pascal.